# code coverage with nyc returning 0% for lines, statement and functions

Tags: node.js, code-coverage, serverless-framework, sinon-chai, nyc

I'm using nodeJS and have created unit tests using sinon,chai along with code coverage nyc. but nyc is returning 0% for statements, lines, functions -

======================== Coverage summary ===============================

Statements : 0% ( 0/34 )
Branches : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions : 0% ( 0/4 )
Lines : 0% ( 0/34 )

app.js -

```
 exports.get  = async (event, context) => {
      try {
           const data = await getResult(13, 'table', 'inbox', false, 2);
           return success(data);
        } catch (err) {
       return failure({ status: false });
     }
   };
```

app.test.unit.js

```
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
const expect = chai.expect;
let event, context;

describe('test get', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('get should return success', async () => {
        // Mock
        const result = { };
        sandbox.stub(lambda, 'getResult').returns(result);

        // Act
        let response = await get(event, context);
        expect(response.statusCode).equal(200);
    });

    it('get should return failure', async () => {
        sandbox.stub(lambda, 'getResult').throws(new Error('whatever'));

        // Act
        let response = await get(event, context);
        console.log(response.body);

        //Expect
        expect(response.statusCode).equal(500);

    });
});
```

Comment: Is the `describe` block correctly formatted or do you actually have back-ticks around it turning it into a template literal?

Comment: yes, back ticks was added for formatting.